VPS with Coolify : increase max size upload in phpmyadmin
Hello I am running a wordpress site on my VPS with Coolify.
I am trying to upload a .sql file of 20M on phpmyadmin. I cannot figure how to increase the size (2048kio by now).
On my VPS, I have a folder and a .ini file :
/sites-graphandco-config/pma-custom-php.ini
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300

Here is my Docker Compose file :
  wordpress:
    image: 'wordpress:latest'
    volumes:
      - 'wordpress-files:/var/www/html'
    environment:
      - SERVICE_FQDN_WORDPRESS
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$SERVICE_USER_WORDPRESS
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$SERVICE_PASSWORD_WORDPRESS
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD
        - curl
        - '-f'
        - 'http://127.0.0.1'
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:8'
    volumes:
      - 'mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql'
      - ./sites-graphandco-config/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$SERVICE_PASSWORD_ROOT
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=$SERVICE_USER_WORDPRESS
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=$SERVICE_PASSWORD_WORDPRESS
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD
        - mysqladmin
        - ping
        - '-h'
        - 127.0.0.1
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
  pma:
    volumes:
      - ./sites-graphandco-config/pma-custom-php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom-php.ini
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.2.1

    ports:
      - '8070:80'
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
      - PMA_PASSWORD=$SERVICE_PASSWORD_ROOT
  ftp:
    image: delfer/alpine-ftp-server
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - '21:21'
      - '21000-21010:21000-21010'
    environment:
      - USERS=**user**|**password**|/var/www/html|10002
    volumes:
      - 'wordpress-files:/var/www/html'

The limit remains unchanged.
What am I missing ?
Thanks in advance

Does the wordpress image use apache to serve content? If so, there is probably an option to adjiust, and this is a duplicate. Let me know

Yes it does use apache. I tried the same config by importing the file in my wordpress volume but the limit in phpmyadmin remained unchanged

This question is similar to: How do you output the current value of LimitRequestBody on Apache 2.4. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What is different is that I am using Docker, I don't know how to persist te setting, how and where to change the param, and how to link to a Dockfile maybe...

No, it's not different. Apache is Apache, and there are many ways to assign a custom .conf file

I'm not familiar with that image, but to start: 1)  you can attach to the running container and do  grep -R LimitRequestBody /etc/apache2  to check if the parameter has been set in a conf file 2) look for  infos in the official page
